# Prepare an activity before show

Tags: android, android-activity

The problem is only when my activity already shown it begins updates and it look no good. How it works: in onStart of activity I send cmd to service to get update data, also I register brodcast listener there. I want to prepare received data from service to show before activity appears. How to do that? Thanks.

How it works now: when I back from another activity first I see old data and then it changes (very fast but you can see it) to new.

Comment: **"I want to show received data from service before activity appears."** : An `Activity` is a UI framework - it's not possible to show anything until the `Activity` appears. Your question is very unclear - please explain more clearly.

Comment: @Squonk used Prepare instead show)

Comment: An `Activity` doesn't have a method to "prepare" it in the way you are asking. If you start an `Activity` from another it will be paused and probably stopped. When you return from the second `Activity` using `BACK` the first `Activity` will be restarted (if it has been stopped) and `onRestart()` will be called - if it has simply been paused then it will be resumed and `onResume()` will be called. There is no way to "prepare" the first `Activity` other than to clear any data showing on the screen in one or other of those methods and then showing the new data.

Comment: @Squonk Thank you for your explanation ,it is really clear . the OP doesn't seem to understand the life cycle and that's what made him post this answer .

Comment: @AIL I know all about activity life cycle dear. But it is real task to work around this situation when u receive data a little bit later that your activity shown.

Comment: @konopko : It's still not clear what you're trying to achieve as you haven't shown any code or explained what your "data" is and how it is displayed. One option might be to clear it from the UI when you start the second `Activity`. In that way you'll return to a blank screen which, as you say, is updated "very fast" and you then won't need to worry about the old data being shown for a short period.

Comment: @Squonk Ok, my data is just some strings I have to show. Problem is that activity gets service broadcast a half of second later than activity shown. In this case no need to show progress, but user see when old data changes to new and this is bad UX.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to setup things before your activity is shown you need to do things in the `onCreate` method instead of `onStart` method.
further informations in android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: But my activity doent destroys, it just stops when I switch to another activity and then back

Comment: yeah ?? and what this has to do with your question ?? you said that you need to perform things between activity is shown you have not mentioned anything about destroying  the activity ot something

Answer (score 0):

When you send the command to the service to update your data, you should change the views in your Activity to show loading indicators, or a blank view, or whatever you want the user to see until the Broadcast comes in that your new data is ready. Then you shouldn't need to worry about old data being visible.

Comment: Not server but Android Service. Callback comes in half of second after activity show and it seems no need to show progress

Comment: Sorry, I meant "service"...I've edited my answer. If there's no need to show progress, then I think you're stuck with the old data. You must do one or the other. I'm not sure what other solution you're looking for.